# Itemized list is appearing outside of margins

Tags: sectioning, lists, memoir, itemize

I am writing a `memoir` document with a subsection that contains a itemized list. This itemized list is not appearing within the margins of text, but instead starts somewhere unknown and only has the last few words of each item in the margin. The rest of the document fits within the margin, just this small section with the list seems to be off.

Apparently I can't post an image but I hope I described it well enough.

Can anyone explain to me what I might need to do to fix this?

Comment: The problem would be much more comprehensible if you add a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) to your question.

Comment: You can still post images - just remove the `!` before the link and someone with editing privileges will embed the image correctly.

Comment: @domotorp, not clear what you want other than use `\item[] text with no bullet` ?

Comment: @David: This did not work for some reason, the text went onto the margin. But using description environment miraculously helped for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has been solved on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=17780).

Since the poster used square brackets for the text, LaTeX treated it like label text and aligns it this way, right aligned with few space. For demonstrating that explanation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [This is a very long text, which goes into the left margin
    and is only partially visible.]
  \item A normal item for comparing.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrog alignment]

So the solution is to remove the square brackets. If square brackets cause such problems with `\item` or other commands, they can be protected by braces `{[...]}` or separated from the command by braces `{}[...]`.

Comment: Why is this a solution to the problem? I have the same issue but I want to name my items, like \item[Step a]. If I do your way, then I will have bullets instead of names.

Comment: @domotorp: Sounds like you should use a `description` environment rather than `itemize`.  Or perhaps use `\begin{itemize}[label={}]` with the `enumitem` package. Instead of describing it, it would be best if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Peter: I see that with enumitem you can do many things, unfortunately I could not figure out what to use. A MWE would be
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\begin{itemize}
\item[{Step (a)}]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

Comment: @Peter: Oops, things worked perfectly with the description environment now, thanks for your help.